# organizing this HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to practice some HTML, CSS, I am trying to copy this website:
[the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0xUN.png)
But I wasn't able to achieve it, anyone got anything in mind to fix it? thanks a lot (PROBLEM): I cannot make the borders show up in the middle, and cannot align the footer to center even tho I did in CSS, and the Ice Cream title did not center.

here is my code so you can try:

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFCCFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

h1 {
    color: #006699;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    background-color: #FF6699;
    font-size: 0.7cm;
    text-align: center;
}

#table1  {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#logo {
    background-color: #FF6699;
    height: 150px;
}

#leftCol {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}

#midCol {
    width: 60%
}

#rightCol {
    width: 20%;
}

th,tr {
        border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Cookies and Cups</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr id="logo">
            <td colspan="3">Ice Cream</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="leftCol" valign="top">
            <td><a href="Home.html">Home</a><br/><a href="Icecream.html">Home Delivery</a><br/><a href="emailClient.html">Contact Us</a></td>
            <td id="midCol" valign="top">We serve Different Ice Creams with different flavors:
                <ul>
                    <li>Strawberry</li>
                    <li>Mint</li>
                    <li>Banana</li>
                    <li>Vanilla, and more...</li>
                </ul>
            451 9th St San <br/>
            Francisco, CA 94103, United States<br/>
            +1 415-437-2877</td>
            <td id="rightCol"><img src="url"></img></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  colspan="3" id="footer">Copyright C 2014 (Student Name)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Lesson 1: Don't use tables for layout. Use tables for tabular data.

Comment: Lesson 2: The time for `Transitional` DTDs is past. We no longer need to use stuff that went out with HTML 3.2 in order to have it work in most browsers. Use HTML 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use tables. Tables are for tabular data.

Go easy on using ID's for styling. Use classes wherever possible. You can only have one unique ID on a page, so your code is not really universal and transportable.

One thing I noticed: you are styling #table1, but have no such ID in your HTML, so that CSS is not going to do anything.

If you want to center with margin auto inside another element (in this case a table cell) you need to apply the margin auto to the element that has to center, not the container.

text-align is applied to the container, but should be used sparingly, and only on text.

Hope this nudges you along.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply, I did add the table1 ID (i forgot about it) also I tried to margin in the table cell too but it did not seem to work still, any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: <span>text</span> span {margin: left: auto; marin-right: auto;}

But, as said: don't use tables. :)